# Change an user his/her password

Tags: symfony4

I try to send an email to the user so that he can reset his password, 
I generated an event with swiftmailer, but when I type an email address in the email form to send an email to the user I have this errors:
when I type an email that exists in the database: error=email already taken

when I type an email that does not exist in the database: error= Call to a member function getUsername() on null.

please, I need help

```
class ChangepasswordController extends Controller
{
public function sendMailAction(Request $request, EventDispatcherInterface 
$eventDispatcher, $email)
{
    $user = new User();
    $form = $this->createForm(SendmailType::class, $user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

        try {
            $user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));


        } catch (ExceptionInterface $e) {
            $this->addFlash('danger', "Cet email n'existe pas.");
        }
        $event = new GenericEvent($user);
        $eventDispatcher->dispatch(Events::USER_RESETPASSWORD , $event);

        return $this->redirect('connexion');


    }
    return $this->render(
        'security/changePassword.html.twig',
        array('form' => $form->createView())
    );

}
}
```

my event:

```
class EventResetpassword implements EventSubscriberInterface
{

private $mailer;
private $sender;
private $twig;

public function __construct(\Swift_Mailer $mailer, $sender, Environment $twig)
{
    $this->mailer = $mailer;
    $this->sender = $sender;
    $this->twig   = $twig;
}

public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        Events:: USER_RESETPASSWORD => 'userResetPassword'

    ];
}


/**
 * @param GenericEvent $event
 * @throws \Twig_Error_Loader
 * @throws \Twig_Error_Runtime
 * @throws \Twig_Error_Syntax
 */
public function userResetPassword(GenericEvent $event): void
{
    /** @var User $user */

    $user = $event->getSubject();
    $username = $user->getUsername();
    $message = (new \Swift_Message())
        ->setSubject($username)
        ->setTo($user->getEmail())
        ->setFrom($this->sender)
        ->setBody($this->twig->render('security/sendemail.html.twig', [
            'username' => $username
        ]));

    $this->mailer->send($message);

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One of problems is that `findOnyBy` will return null when there is no user with email address and not throw exception.

you have to do null check:

```
$user = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(User::class)
            ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));


if(null !== $user){
    $event = new GenericEvent($user);
    $eventDispatcher->dispatch(Events::USER_RESETPASSWORD , $event);

    return $this->redirect('connexion');
}
$this->addFlash('danger', "Cet email n'existe pas.");
```

Other problem is that `$email` can't be injected in your action by magic, if it's not parameter of your route.
Since You are using form you have to get data from your form. `$form->getData()` in your case this will return `User` instance with email set. This is also wrong since it's not user so it doesn't make any sense. You should use simple value object/DTO which would have only email, this way you can avoid confusion.

You should really read doc about forms in symfony:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/forms.html

https://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/forms.html

This is also good read, about how to do it (and you should do it this way :) )

https://blog.martinhujer.cz/symfony-forms-with-request-objects/

One more thing never use `ExceptionInterface`, just Exceptions you can except, this way you can suppress unexpected stuff and have much bigger problems later which are hard to debug.

Comment: Thanks, but my object is null, when I type an email in the form, I cant send mail for a user with my event because of $email =null

Comment: I updated my answer, your example has more problems than I spot for first time.

Comment: If it solved your problem, you should accept the answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Also you should add new code by editing you question. And If answer helped you and problem is solved, there is no need to post final code.

Answer (score 0):

```
I update my Code: 

  /**
 * @Route("/send-mail", name="send_mail")
 * @Method({"GET", "POST"})
 * @param Request $request
 * @return Response
 */
public function sendMailAction(Request $request, EventDispatcherInterface $eventDispatcher, GenerateToken $token)
{
    $form = $this->createForm(SendMailType::class);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        $email = $form->get('email')->getData();
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        /** @var User $user */
        if ($user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByEmail($email)) {
            $user->setToken($token->generateToken());
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();

            $event = new GenericEvent($user);
            $eventDispatcher->dispatch(Events::USER_RESETPASSWORD, $event);
        }
        return $this->redirectToRoute('check_email');

    }

    return $this->render('security/change_password.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  /**
 * @Route("/change-password/{token}", name="change_password")
 * @Method={"POST"}
 * @param Request $request
 * @param string $token
 * @return Response
 */
public function changePasswordAction(Request $request, UserPasswordEncoderInterface $passwordEncoder,  $token)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    /** @var User $user */
    $user = $em->getRepository(User::class)->findOneByToken($token);
    $form = $this->createForm(ResetPasswordType::class);

    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {

    $password = $form->get('password')->getData();
    $passwordencoded = $passwordEncoder->encodePassword($user, $password);
    $user->setPassword($passwordencoded);
    $user->setToken(null);
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();

    $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'votre mot de passe est bien réinitialisé vous pouvez vous connecter'
        );
    return $this->redirectToRoute('login');

    }

    return $this->render('security/reset_password.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ]);
}
```

class GenerateToken
{

```
public function generateToken()
{
    $token= md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
    return $token;
}
```

}